# Ruby hash to XML: How would I create duplicate keys in a hash for repeated XML xpaths?

Tags: ruby, xml

I have to create XML that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<FirstLevel>
  <Package>
    <Name></Name>
  </Package>
  <Package>
    <Name></Name>
  </Package>
  ...
</FirstLevel>
```

As you can see, `Package` shows up multiple times at the same level in the structure.

I know you can't have duplicate keys in a Ruby hash, so I don't know how I would be able to go from a hash to XML when there are duplicate keys. Does anyone have any ideas?

I'm using `Hash#to_xml` to convert my hash to XML (made available by ActiveSupport I believe).

By the way, I'm using Rails.

Comment: Also you can use nokogiri xml to use/access the xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I believe I figured it out. You have to use `Hash#compare_by_identity`. I believe this makes it so that the key lookups are done using object id as opposed to string matches.

I found it in "[Ruby Hash with duplicate keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808801/ruby-hash-with-duplicate-keys)".

`{}.compare_by_identity`

```
    h1 = {}
    h1.compare_by_identity
    h1["a"] = 1
    h1["a"] = 2
    p h1 # => {"a"=>1, "a"=>2}
```