# Deep hiera lookup in a ruby template returns last result only

Tags: puppet, erb, hiera

I have the following hiera:

```
profile::example::firewalls:
  - serverclass1:
    label: http
    port: 80
    label: https
    port: 443
  - serverclass2:
    label: ssh
    port: 22
    label: telnet
    port: 21
```

I try to call it in the following way in an erb template:

```
<% @example = scope().call_function('hiera',['profile::example::firewalls']) -%>
show me the array!
<%= @example %>
```

Oddly this returns the following:

```
+show me the array!
+[{"serverclass1"=>nil, "label"=>"https", "port"=>443}, {"serverclass2"=>nil, "label"=>"telnet", "port"=>21}]
```

Once I have a complete array I'll eventually use this within a for/each loop within ruby, but for the moment this seems to return just the final result and not everything I'd expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem begins in your YAML data structure, that contains duplicate "label" keys. That is why some of your data is missing in the output.

(See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808801/ruby-hash-with-duplicate-keys) related Stack Overflow answer for more info.)

Although it is not entirely clear what you are trying to do, it seems to me that you would be better with a YAML data structure like this:

```yaml
profile::example::firewalls:
  serverclass1:
    http: 80
    https: 443
  serverclass2:
    ssh: 22
    telnet: 21
```

You could then iterate through that in the ERB template using code like:

```erb
<% scope().call_function('lookup',['profile::example::firewalls']).each do |server_class, data| -%>
Server class: <%= server_class %>
  <%- data.each do |key, value| -%>
  <%= key %> --- <%= value %>
  <%- end -%>
<% end -%>
```

Note also that I removed the deprecated `hiera()` function and replaced it with `lookup()`.

Comment: Thanks Alex, after some time that's exactly what I ended up doing! I was hoping there would be  cleaner cut way of doing this but evidently there isn't! Thanks (my code looks almost identical to this so I feel pleased I was on the right track).